# Jagged edges on the Droid Serif font only in Chrome on Mac OSX

Tags: fonts, css, font-face, google-font-api

I'm having a rather strange issue with how Droid Serif (Bold-italic) displays in Chrome on OSX. Basically, if the font appears above the fold, it displays jagged. After it's highlighted, it smooths out. This happens on all pages with the Droid Serif font in Chrome on OSX. Check out the following URL:

http://adamjohnsondesign.com/contact/

What in the world is going on here? Any suggestions? See the images below.

Highlighted with half smooth and half jagged: http://i.min.us/inK36.png

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're experiencing is an `@font-face` bug in newer (recent) versions of Chrome on Mac OS X.

For example, I see the jagged edges you're describing when using Chrome 11 and Chrome 12 on Mac OS X.

When I view your page in [Chrome 9 on Mac OS X](http://mac.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php) (9.0.597.44) or [Chrome 10 on Mac OS X](http://mac.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php) (10.0.648.204) I see the smooth, anti-aliased Droid Serif font as expected.

Since no other browsers seem to exhibit this problem, this leads me to believe it's a font bug in Chrome on OS X.

Moreover, if you select (highlight) text using the Droid Serif font or scroll down the page, the browser redraws the font with smooth edges — this gives further credence to the buggy behavior.

Comment: On second thought, perhaps it's not a bug in Chrome, but a conflict with other assets on your site. If you download this [Droid Serif font kit](http://www.mediafire.com/?io9nqet38b8wdp0) generated from FontSquirrel, you'll see the Droid Serif Bold Italic renders smoothly even in Chrome 11+.

Comment: I'm rather certain I tried that a while back but I will give it another go. I think I've also tried viewing Droid Serif via the Google Font Directory in Chrome on OSX and it looked fine--which leads me to believe that it would be an assets issue (gulp!). I'll keep you posted. More suggestions are welcome & thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Using native `@font-face` rules are easier than what you might think. The font kit from FontSquirrel has already done everything for you -- just copy and paste their CSS into your stylesheets and upload the fonts. Make sure the fonts are being served from the same domain as your site, so you don't encounter the cross-domain origin policy. Then you can remove all dependence upon the Google Fonts API JavaScript.

Comment: How could this *not* be a bug in chrome?  Regardless of the other stuff on the site, this doesn't look like behavior that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this, the issue turned out to be something to do with a custom template I was using within the CMS I use for that site. Other users had reported similar issues with a variety of @font-face fonts. By not using that specific custom template, the issue went away (almost) entirely.

For more information on the subject, check out this thread:

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/interrresting-just-figured-out-c5and039s-auto-nav-block-interfer/#54983

As a note, the answer marked correct in that thread offers a different solution to the problem; however, that was not the solution for my site (I was already doing that).

Thanks to everyone for the help!